# How can I redirect a Blogger blog to another blog

Tags: redirects, html, blogger, blogspot

I have a blogger blog with its own domain (I'll call it *www.example.com*); that's to say: this site used to be a *www.example.blogspot.com* and I purchased a name domain later; I can continue to manage settings from the Blogger control panel.

Now, another webmaster will write my name on a page of her website and I'd like her to insert a hyperlink to let users be redirected to mine (when they click on my name).
BUT I don't want to provide the URL of my website because I'd like to be able to immediately stop redirecting if I change idea (in case I no longer want my website to be associated to others).

This is the reason why I created another blogger blog (I'll call it *www.bloggerblog2.blogspot.com*) and I'm trying to use this new address to redirect to *www.example.com*.
I cant't do that from the settings of Blogger because I get an error. More specifically, I'm on `Settings -> Search preferences -> Custom Redirects -> New Redirects.` At this point I write the two URL addresses and save but I get the error message

> The source and destination values cannot be empty or more than 256
>   characters and must start with /.

I wonder why I'm getting this error?
May I handle this by editing the HTML code of the blog (and how)?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because Blogger only allows redirects **inside** your blog.

For your purpose, You could buy another domain name and redirect it to your blog or use a url minifyer to hide your example.com in the links.